# How do I properly add a python shell to the shells file under /etc/shells?

Tags: linux, shell, python3, metasploit

I would also like to do the same for metasploit. I know that using Kali would be more practical but my PC isn't good enough to run it on VB.

Comment: You can enter the full path of it on one line in `/etc/shells` - avoid spaces, special characters, etc

Answer (score 2):

Several ways:

- `sudo vi /etc/shells`
- `printf "%s\n" "/path/to/shell" | sudo tee -a /etc/shells`
- `ed /etc/shells` # `a`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`/path/to/shell`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`.`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`wq`<kbd>Enter</kbd>